# Formato Json no retorno

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso passar um json com o seguinte formato:

```
{rows:[
    { 
     data:[
       "1",
       "Nome teste",
       "Descricao teste"]
}]}
```

Mas ao usar em minha action jsonresult, não sei como retornar dessa forma

```
 public JsonResult Data()
    {
      var grupos= grupoService.BuscaTodos();

      return Json(new
      {
        rows = new
        {
          data = grupos
        }
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

ele acaba retornando assim:

```
{"rows":{
      "data":[{
             "Nome":"nome",
              "Descricao":"descricao",
              "Id":110,
              "DataCadastro":null}]
}}
```

Alguém sabe me informar o que preciso fazer?

Azul é como eu quero, vermelho é como está vindo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você queria que o id ficasse fora do data?

Comment: ignore o id, rsrs,gostaria que ficasse exatamente dessa forma, sem o uso de "Propriedade":"valor",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente ao seu layout seria assim:

```
return Json(new
        {
            rows = new object[] {
                new {
                    data = new string[]
                    {
                        "1", "NomeTeste", "Descricao Teste"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Se for uma lista por exemplo:

```
var dados = new object[] 
{
    new object[] {"1", "NomeTeste 1", "Descricao Teste 1" },
    new object[] {"2", "NomeTeste 2", "Descricao Teste 2" }
};

return Json(new
{
    rows = new object[] {
        new {
            data =  dados
        }
    }
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Com uma classe:

```
public class Exemplo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataCadatro { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
IList<Exemplo> dados = new List<Exemplo>();
dados.Add(new Exemplo()
{
    Id = 1,
    Nome = "NomeTeste 1",
    Descricao = "Descricao 1"
});
dados.Add(new Exemplo()
{
    Id = 2,
    Nome = "NomeTeste 2",
    Descricao = "Descricao 2"
});
```

---

```
return Json(new
    {
        rows = new object[] {
            new {
                data =  dados.Select(x => new object[]{
                    x.Id.ToString(), x.Nome.ToString(), x.Descricao.ToString()
                })
            }
        }
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Forçando somente o primeiro item da lista:

```
return Json(new
    {
        rows = new object[] {
            new {
                data =  dados.Select(x => new object[]{
                    x.Id, x.Nome.ToString(), x.Descricao.ToString()
                })
                .FirstOrDefault()
            }
        }
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a ***Nova Edição*** ficou mais claro o layout:

```
IList<Exemplo> dados = new List<Exemplo>();
dados.Add(new Exemplo()
{
    Id = 1,
    Nome = "NomeTeste 1",
    Descricao = "Descricao 1"
});
dados.Add(new Exemplo()
{
    Id = 2,
    Nome = "NomeTeste 2",
    Descricao = "Descricao 2"
});

return Json(new
{
    rows = dados.Select(x => new 
            {
                x.Id, 
                Data = new object[] { 
                    x.Id, x.Nome.ToString(), x.Descricao.ToString()
                }                            
            })                                    
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Exatamente o que queria, obrigado! mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
    public JsonResult Data()
    {
        var grupos = grupoService.BuscaTodos().Select(data => new
        {
            data.Id,
            data.Nome,
            data.Descricao
        });
        return Json(new
        {
            rows = new
            {
                data = grupos
            }
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: nada =/ estou vendo o formato que ele vem nesse reader aqui: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu, mas é quase isso, =s

Comment: Nesse meu exemplo ele retorna como?

Comment: {"rows":{"data":[{"Id":110,"Nome":"nome","Descricao":"descricao"}]}}